# How do I multiply each element in a list of list by a number?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list of list:

```
my_list = [[1, 2, 3],[ 4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]]
```

How can I multiply each element in my_list by 2? The output should be:

```
[[2, 4, 6],[ 8, 10, 10],[14, 16, 18]]
```

Comment: what have you tried? should the output be a new list or should it be modified in place? are you doing this kind of thing a lot because then you might want to use `numpy` because there it's just `2 * numpy.array(my_list)`

Comment: I am trying to plot points in 3d using matplotlib I have a list of [x,y,z] coordinates in float. I need to multiply them by 1000 so to work only with integers. Any pointer to how to plot such a kind of list will be welcomed. Yes I would like to modify it in place (I suspect)

Comment: ok if you are working with matplotlib you almost certainly want to be using numpy then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using list comprehensions:

```
def multiply_2D_list(l, by=2):
    return [[i * by for i in sub_list] for sub_list in l]

my_list = [[1, 2, 3],[ 4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]]
print(multiply_2D_list(my_list))
```

Using numpy

```
import numpy as np
my_list = [[1, 2, 3],[ 4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]]
print((np.array(my_list) * 2).tolist())
```

Using numpy requires sublists to have the same number of elements though